# How to prevent Pandas to_dict() from converting timestamps to string?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with a *date* field which appear to be represented as unix timestamps. When i call `df.to_dict()` on it the dates are getting converted to a string like this **yyyy-mm-dd** .... how can I prevent this from happening?

I'm using the code to return a JSON in my FastAPI app ...

```
df_results = pd.read_sql_query(sql_query_str, _engine)

return_object["results"] = df_results.to_dict(orient='records')
# outputs "date": 2021-12-31" in the json

return_object["results"] = json.loads(df_results.to_json(orient='records'))
# outputs "date": 1640908800000 in the json
```

Comment: i've edited the question to  show the 2 lines of code that I am alternating between with the different results ... hope that helps

Comment: I've added it but I dont think it will help! its just getting the data from my postgressql DB (date type). Is it perhaps a casting issue by pandas when it reads the data in?

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the data type before using `.to_dict()`. Calling it as an integer should keep the UNIX timestamp e.g

```
df.astype(int).to_dict()
```